# Sorting array by time attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of appointment objects, and I would like to sort by starts_at attribute.

`my_array.uniq.sort_by! {|obj| obj.starts_at}`

However, I got the following error:
`comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with nil failed`

I am sure I don't have any nil value for starts_at. What's the problem here? 
Also, how can I sort by descending?

**Update 1:** I realized that uniq! gives me nil when I call .all method to my Appointment class. Without uniq, it works fine.

`Appointment.all.uniq!`

**Update 2:** I can't apply minus to obj.starts_at. It gives me error:method - can't be found with UTC time format. Probably b/c time does not allowed to be zero. Any thoughts on overcome this?

**Update 3:** `my_array.uniq.sort { |x, y| (x.starts_at || nil) <=> (y.starts_at || nil)}` works in console, but when I ran my app, it says `comparison of Event with Event failed`

**Last update:** The following works:

`@events.sort_by!{|obj| (obj.starts_at.nil? ? 3.years.ago : obj.starts_at.utc)}`

I need to convert date format to .utc, and handle missing starts_at (sorry I don't know why I have missing starts_at attribute on an object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have association of blog_post has many blog_comments and i sort array of blog_post according

to blog_comments count and it is running fine......

```
  @sort_blog = @blog_posts.sort_by { |i| i.blog_comments.count }
```

I think you are doing fine but problem is some where you have nil object you can try like this

```
  my_array.uniq.sort_by! {|obj| obj.starts_at  unless obj.blank?}
```

Try it.........

Answer (score 2):

You certainly HAVE an element with a nil starts_at attribute (but not necessarily a nil element in the array).  However your other (I'm afraid the bigger) problem is that #sort_by! after #uniq does not modify your original array, just the temporary one existing between the uniq and sort.

```
tmp = my_array.find_all { |e| e and e.starts_at }
my_array = tmp.uniq.sort_by { |obj| obj.starts_at }
```

Or if you like, you can write it more human readable:

```
    ... find_all { |e| not e.nil? and not e.starts_at.nil? }
```

...but first of all, find out how can starts_at be nil.

Comment: Hi Sandor, I actually checked and there's no nil starts_at. But uniq! gives me nil. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
my_array.sort { |x, y| (x.starts_at || nil) <=> (y.starts_at || nil)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a nil object in your array?

Try this:

```
my_array.a.compact!
my_array.uniq.sort_by! {|obj| obj.starts_at}
```

Credit to Michael Kohl for the idiom (see comment).

These are equivalent:

```
my_array.reject!{|x| nil==x}   # my original answer 
my_array.reject!{|x| x.nil? }  # better idiom -- thanks Michael
my_array.compact!              # best idiom -- thanks Michael
```

Comment: Your first version is the same as `a.compact!`. Without that method, `x.nil?` inside the block would be more idiomatic btw.

Comment: `compact!` is standard Ruby, not Rails (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact-21).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
my_array.keep_if { |obj| obj.started_at }.uniq!.sort_by! {|obj| - obj.starts_at}
```

note that appending `-` will make your array to be sorted descending

Comment: desc sorting will not work with time. ```NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for 2013-04-04 12:51:06 UTC:Time```